# How to make color as alpha (remove a color) in SFML?

Tags: c++, graphics, textures, sprite, sfml

I have a texture in the sprite and I want to make background invisible (white color).

```
sf::Texture texBohatera;
texBohatera.loadFromFile("bohater.png");

sf::Sprite bohater;
bohater.setTexture(texBohatera);
```

Comment: cannot compute. more data is needed.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista I have a PNG file with white background color and I want to display this image in SFML without white background color (only with my Player image)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
sf::Image image;
image.LoadFromFile("bohater.png");
image.CreateMaskFromColor(sf::Color::White);

sf::Texture texBohatera;
texBohatera.LoadFromImage(image);

sf::Sprite bohater;
bohater.SetTexture(texture);
```

(Disclaimer, I didn't test it because I don't want to install SFML)

Answer (score 0):

you could

`window.clear(sf::Color::White);`

or find a program that allows you to draw png files like piskel.

you can either import the file and erase the areas you want transparent. 
 or draw your own sprite.